# vtkDistanceWidget zoom in and zoom out bug

Tags: c++, vtk

I tried a vtkDistanceWidget object, and I saw something strange in his behaviour:
To reproduce this, just follow:

```
1.Draw a distance;
2.Do zoom; Result: vtkDistanceWidget bounds (are cross shapes) are following zoomed image.
3.Move one vtkDistanceWidget bound (or both of them);
4.Do zoom again;
```

Result: vtkDistanceWidget bounds (are cross shapes) are not following zoomed image. Only when I hover my mouse of the cross shapes is when it is updated. How do I fix this so that cross shapes are updated with the zoom.

```
Source code to reproduce vtkDistanceWidget (possible) bug:
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkDistanceWidget.h>
#include <vtkDistanceRepresentation.h>
#include <vtkSphereSource.h>
 
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
///*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // A renderer and render window
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
 
    // An interactor
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
 
    // A sphere
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
    sphereSource->SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    sphereSource->SetRadius(4.0);
    sphereSource->SetPhiResolution(40);
    sphereSource->SetThetaResolution(8);
    sphereSource->Update();
 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());
 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    renderer->AddActor(actor);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDistanceWidget> distanceWidget =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkDistanceWidget>::New();
    distanceWidget->SetInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
    distanceWidget->CreateDefaultRepresentation();
    static_cast<vtkDistanceRepresentation*>(distanceWidget->GetRepresentation())->SetLabelFormat("%-#6.3g mm");
 
    // Render an image (lights and cameras are created automatically)
    renderWindow->Render();
 
    renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
    renderWindow->Render();
    distanceWidget->On();
 
    // Begin mouse interaction
    renderWindowInteractor->Start();
///*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I remember that was a vtk bug that has been solved in the latest version (greater than 8). Which version you use ?

Comment: I am using VTK 9.0 now. Still didn't fix the bug unfortunately